# How to filter a JSON by a string value contained in an array inside JSON using JSONPath

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I am listing down my sample JSON below,
I want to write a JSONPath that selects element when subjects has (or contains) "Maths".

NOTE: I am using Goessner's JSONPath using Newtonsoft library (C#)**

```
{
   "class":{
      "type":"group",
      "identifier":"MyFavClass",
      "subs":[
         {
            "type":"individual",
            "identifier":"Rambo"
         },
         {
            "type":"individual",
            "identifier":"Rancho"
         },
         {
            "type":"biggroup",
            "identifier":"village",
            "subjects":[
               "Maths",
               "English"
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"biggroup",
            "identifier":"newvillage",
            "subjects":[
               "Maths"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried?  2) *I want to write a JSONPath that selects element when subjects has (or contains) "Maths".* - what elements do you want to select, exactly?  Are they the elements of the `"class.subs[*].subjects[*]"` array, or the container `"class.subs[*]"` array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Json.NET's [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) method for your [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) queries, you may find all math subjects using the following query:

```
var value = "Maths";

var subjects = root.SelectTokens($"class.subs[*].subjects[?(@ == '{value}')]");
```

Of course this will just return a sequence of `JValue` tokens with value `"Maths"`.  If you want the `class.subs[*]` objects whose `subjects[*]` arrays contains `"Maths"`, you may do:

```
var subs = root.SelectTokens($"class.subs[?(@.subjects[?(@ == '{value}')])]");
```

Notes:

- `[?(...)]` applies a filter expression `...` to an array.
- In a filter expression, array contents that are primitive values may be matched using the `@` symbol for the current object.
- Json.NET's implementation of JSONPath supports nested queries inside array filter expressions.  Thus `[?(@.subjects[?(@ == '{value}')])]` matches array items that have an item in their `"subjects"` array that matches the value parameter.
- Note that search values that contain a single quote character `'` must be escaped as shown in [Querying JSON with JSON Path and escaped properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm).  Thus if the string to be matched was `Math's` you would need to escape it like so:

  ```
  var value = "Math's".Replace("'", "\\\'");
  ```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rpNaPd).